# Is there any control panel like Kloxo on Ubuntu? How to install it?

Tags: ubuntu, control-panel

I bought a VPS yesterday, and install ubuntu 9 for it. Kloxo is very good but it seems like only support RedHat and CentOS. So i want to ask if there is any control panel like it on ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/index.html) is the best alternative for you. It's an open source "control panel" that is compatible with just about every Linux distro out there.

You can find the wiki [here](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin).

Comment: is virtual host supported by webmin?

Answer (score -1):

You can try open panel. It's not exactly kloxo but...

Comment: And this is not exactly an answer.